How to convert a binary file with extension .GRD to .TXT in R?
I have 20 binary files with .grd extension for rainfall (0.25 X 0.25 degree) that I downloaded from Indian Meteorological Department website from 2000 to 2020.
The data are arranged in 135x129 grid points. The first data in the record is at 6.5N & 66.5E, the second is at 6.5N & 66.75E, and so on. The last data record corresponds to 38.5N & 100.0E. The yearly data file consists of 365/366 records corresponding to non leap/ leap years.
I need to convert these files to text files using R. How do I read binary files with extension. grd in r and convert them to .txt and then merge all 20 files to form a single file?
I went through some earlier posts including this but was not able to convert the .grd files to .txt files

It follows these simple steps:

Read your binary file into R using readBin()

Convert it to a character file using paste(as.character(yourfile.bin),collapse = " ")

Export it as a text file using writeLines(yourfile,"yourfile.txt")


Hope this helps!

Thank you. I was able to convert the  files using the below
`con <- file(input_file, "rb")
data <- readBin(con, numeric(), n = 135 * 129 * 366, size = 4, endian = "little")
close(con)
data_char <- paste(as.character(data), collapse = " ")
writeLines(data_char, output_file)
}
input_files <- list.files(pattern = "\.grd$", full.names = TRUE)
Convert each file
for (i in seq_along(input_files)) {
input_file <- input_files[i]
output_file <- paste0("converted_", i, ".txt")
convert_grd_to_txt(input_file, output_file)
print(paste("Converted", input_file, "to", output_file))
}`

Great! Happy for you man!
